# Python: How to stream from stdout of subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am targeting to implement a tiny Python written script to handle Jupyter easier to me.

Therefore I wrote this script:

```py
import signal
import socket
import subprocess
import sys

sp = None
port = 8888


def get_own_ip():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    try:
        s.connect(('1.1.1.1', 1))
        IP = s.getsockname()[0]
    except:
        IP = '127.0.0.1'
    finally:
        s.close()
    return IP


def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    # terminates Jupyter by sending two SIGINTs to it
    if sp is not None:
        # send termination to jupyter
        sp.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
        sp.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)

        sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    own_ip = get_own_ip()

    sp = subprocess.Popen(["jupyter-notebook"
                           , "--ip='%s'" % own_ip
                           , "--port=%i" % port
                           , "--no-browser"],
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                          stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                          bufsize=1)

    print(sp)

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

    with sp.stdout:
        print('read')
        for line in sp.stdout.readline():
            print('line: %s' % line)
    print('wait')
    sp.wait()  # wait for the subprocess to exit
```

First I retrieve my IP address in order to use it as an argument to Jupyter. Then I run Jupyter and then I would like to filter some output from Jupyter (`stdout`) while Jupyter is running. But it seems, that `sp.stdout.readline()` blocks.

The code above produces the following output to the terminal:

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/alex/.scripts/get_own_ip.py
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7fa956374240>
read
[I 22:43:31.611 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/alex/.scripts
[I 22:43:31.611 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 22:43:31.611 NotebookApp] http://192.168.18.32:8888/?token=c4b7784d784206fc357b8f484b8d659fed6a2b1733b46ae6
[I 22:43:31.611 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=c4b7784d784206fc357b8f484b8d659fed6a2b1733b46ae6
[I 22:43:31.611 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 22:43:31.614 NotebookApp] 

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/alex/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-18280-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://192.168.18.32:8888/?token=c4b7784d784206fc357b8f484b8d659fed6a2b1733b46ae6
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=c4b7784d784206fc357b8f484b8d659fed6a2b1733b46ae6
```

You can see that output occurs, but will not be recognised by `sp.stdout.readline()`.

How to correctly stream from `sp.stdout`?

---

Following the hint of @Douglas Myers-Turnbull I changed my main function to:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    own_ip = get_own_ip()
    # store ip as byte stream
    own_ip_bstr = own_ip.encode()

    sp = subprocess.Popen(["jupyter-notebook"
                           , "--ip='%s'" % own_ip
                           , "--port=%i" % port
                           , "--no-browser"],
                          stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                          stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                          bufsize=1)

    # set up handler to terminate jupyter
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

    with open('jupyter.log', mode='wb') as flog:
        for line in sp.stderr:
            flog.write(line)
            if own_ip_bstr in line.strip():
                with open('jupyter.url', mode='w') as furl:
                    furl.write(line.decode().split('NotebookApp] ')[1])
                break

        for line in sp.stderr:
            flog.write(line)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You need to capture stderr instead!

I think those messages are being written to stderr rather than stdout.
So you need to use `sp.stderr` instead.
That's common with the python `logging` framework.

You can test that this is the case by running this in your shell (if you're on Linux):

```
jupyter notebook > stdout.log 2> stderr.log
```

#### If the buffer starts filling up...

You probably won't encounter this issue with output from just jupyter notebook, but I've previously run into an error where the output buffer filled up before my calling code could process it. You need to make sure your code processes lines from stdout (and/or stderr) at least as quickly as jupyter notebook writes lines.
If that's not the case, you can process the lines by stuffing them into queues. Something like this:

```py
    def _reader(cls, pipe_type, pipe, queue):
        """Read in lines of text (utf-8) and add them into the queue."""
        try:
            with pipe:
                for line in iter(pipe.readline, b""):
                    queue.put((pipe_type, line))
        finally:
            queue.put(None)
#
    def stream_cmd(log_callback):
        """Stream lines of stdout and stderr into a queue, then call log_callback on them.
        By putting the lines into a queue and processing with log_callback on another thread, it's ok if log_callback takes a bit longer than the output.
        """
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=cwd, bufsize=1)
        try:
            q = Queue()
            Thread(target=_reader, args=[1, p.stdout, q]).start()
            Thread(target=_reader, args=[2, p.stderr, q]).start()
            for _ in range(2):
                for source, line in iter(q.get, None):
                    log_callback(source, line)
            exit_code = p.wait(timeout=timeout_secs)
        finally:
            p.kill()
        if exit_code != 0:
            raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(
                exit_code, " ".join(cmd), "<<unknown>>", "<<unknown>>"
            )
```

I've successfully used similar code before, but there might be errors in that code.

Comment: Yes, you gave the final important hint - the output goes to `stderr`!